# Does setting an epoll_event.events bits to zero "disables" an event, like EV_DISABLE in the kqueue?

Tags: c, linux, epoll

If the bits of `epoll_event.events` field is zeroed, does it disables the event?

The `kqueue` has `EV_DISABLE`, that

> EV_DISABLE        Disable the event so kevent() will not return it.
> The filter itself is not disabled.

```
epoll_event ev;
ev.data.fd = 0; /* stdin file descriptor */
ev.events = EPOLLIN;
epoll_ctl(epollfd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, evfd, &ev);
ev.events = 0;
epoll_ctl(epollfd, EPOLL_CTL_MOD, evfd, &ev);
```

So, does the above makes the `stdout` event not being reported to `epoll_wait` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, a 0 events field doesn't disable checking the associated file descriptor for events. `EPOLLHUP` in particular will get returned even if it's not explicitly asked for.

You have to remove the descriptor from the epoll interest list, and re-add it when you want to resume monitoring it.

Comment: Will the `signalfd` and `eventfd` also has `EPOLLHUP`?

Comment: I managed to find a time to look into source of `eventpoll.c`. The `EPOLL_CTL_ADD` flag adds up the `EPOLLERR | EPOLLHUP` flags. Sorry about interrupting you, I could have managed to look into the source earlier.